# MySQL UNION function but with duplicates

Tags: mysql, union

Is there a function working like UNION on different SELECT statements that does not remove duplicates? Or any other way of creating one big column out of few smaller ones without loosing any data?

Example:

INPUT

```
col_1,    col_2,    
text1    text3        
text2    text2        
text3    text1
```

OUTPUT

```
col_3
text1
text2
text3
text3
text2
text1
```

Comment: use `UNION ALL` instead

Comment: If only someone thought to collate useful titbits like this into some kind of online resource.